# Why does the code inside this "if" statement still run?

Tags: python, if-statement, equality

I have the following python function:

```
api_function:
    try:
        # api query
    except:
        # api error #1
        return "api error 1"
    except:
        # api error #2
        return "api error 2"
    else: 
        return api_data_dict
```

I want to run this function, and if there's no error, parse the data returned from the API:

```
for call in api_call_list:
    raw_api_data = api_function(access_token)
        if raw_api_data != 'api error 1' or 'api error 2':
            page_name = raw_api_data['name']
            # process api data
```

When I run the code, it runs fine as long as the API is working. However, when the API hits an error, the `if` statement doesn't seem to catch the string--instead, I get the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api_retriever.py", line 4, in <module>
    page_name = raw_api_data['name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Why isn't my `if` statement catching the error string returned by my `api_function` and preventing line 4 from even running?

Comment: Catching exceptions and returning error codes - which the caller must check - instead of letting the caller catch exceptions is a rather strange pattern. Or should I say an antipattern ?

Comment: No idea how I would otherwise structure this. I only want to parse the api data if the api call returned successfully. Can't really put the logic for processing api data inside the api calling function because I use that function multiple times, and each time I want to process the data slightly differently.

Comment: Either you let the exceptions propagate and catch them at the upper level (eventually wrapping them for simplicity if there are too many different exception types) or you catch them _and log them_ at the `api_function` level and then just return `None`. The whole point of having exceptions is to avoid error codes...

Comment: That makes sense in theory, I don't think it applies here in practice just because I don't want to log the errors if they're rate-limiting--it's expected behavior and I'll simply add wait statements that vary depending on which type of rate-limiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of your code:

```
if raw_api_data != 'api error 1' or 'api error 2':
```

is actually interpreted as

```
if (raw_api_data != 'api error 1') or ('api error 2'):
```

and in Python a non-empty string would always evaluate to True.

You shall use:

```
if (raw_api_data != 'api error 1') and (raw_api_data != 'api error 2'):
```

or

```
if not raw_api_data in ('api error 1', 'api error 2'):
```

Comment: The Code under "You shall use:" would always enter the if. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`Or` is Called Logical OR Operator. If any of the two operands are non zero then then condition becomes true. ([source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm))

Use this instead:

```
if (raw_api_data != 'api error 1') and (raw_api_data != 'api error 2'):
```